# Cypress + Docker + Apple Silicon / Arm

Tags: docker, arm, cypress, apple-m1

I am trying to dockerize my tests and run them on M1 (Arm).
my Dockerfile looks like that:

```
FROM cypress/browsers:latest

WORKDIR /projectName

COPY package.json .
COPY tsconfig.json .
COPY cypress.config.ts .
COPY /cypress .
COPY makefile .

RUN npm install -g yarn
RUN yarn install

CMD tail -f /dev/null
```

I then use a Makefile with a few commands:

```
build_docker_arm:
    sudo docker build ${ARM_PLATFORM} -t projectName .
start_docker_arm:
    docker run ${ARM_PLATFORM} -d -t -i -v `pwd`/cypress:/fenrir/cypress -name=projectName projectName
run_docker_chrome:
    docker exec -t -i projectName npx cypress run --browser chrome --spec "cypress/e2e/features/*"
```

When I run `make run_docker_chrome` I get this

[image: chrome not found]

If I try to run without the `--browser chrome` then the tests work

[image: electron pass]

Answer (score 0):

See open issue in cypress:

Add Arm browsers to linux/arm64 Docker images
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-docker-images/issues/695

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).